# macro for writing vectors

Tags: macros, vector

I want to simplify codes for writing vectors. For example, if I write

```
\vector{1,2,3}
```

it would be equivalent to

```
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}
```

Similarly

```
\vector{1,2,3,4}
```

would be

```
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
```

How can I create a macro for this type of work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `stackengine` package already supports this construction with `\bracketVectorstack`, which I bundle in the form asked for by the OP.  Of course, it is not actually using `bmatrix`.

Note that if matrix construction is needed rather than vectors, look for the extensions provided by the `tabstackengine` package.  Also, the inter-row baselineskip can be altered with, for example, `\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\Vector[1]{\setstackEOL{,}\bracketVectorstack{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
X = \Vector{1,2,3,4} \ne \Vector{1,x,3}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The splitting is quite easy with `expl3` syntax and a wrapper command, say `\feqvector`. This example does allow for setting the separator and the type of the matrix, say `b` or `p` or any other allowed type.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_feq_vector_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\feqvector}{O{\\}mO{b}}{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_feq_vector_clist {#2} % Set the list
  \begin{#3matrix}
  \clist_use:Nn \l_feq_vector_clist {#1} % show it with separator from #1 (\\)
  \end{#3matrix}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
A few: $\feqvector{1,2,3}$

More of them: $\feqvector{1,2,3,4,5}$

horizontal: $\feqvector[&]{1,2,3,4,5}$

Now with parenthesis and horizontal: $\feqvector[&]{1,2,3}[p]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There should not be braces around `N` arguments (although in many cases they do no harm); there's no need to clear the clist, if you set it afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

If you can accept a bit different syntax (one character more in the first case), there is a simple solution:

`\def\vector#1.{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}`

with usage

`\vector 1\\2\\3.` or `\vector 1\\2\\3\\4.`

Certainly, dot as the end of argument(s) is only an example.