# Pass a list of arguments to a matrix: issue with last step in iteration

Tags: expl3, arrays, latex3, tabularray

I wish to define a command like `\myrowvector{values={1,2,3}}` and have spacing details set in the preamble. I have adapted code by [user31729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423115/) to great effect, except... **How should I deal with the last step in the iteration?** I would like to prevent the insertion of a separator `&` (row vector) or `\\` (column vector).

In order to increase spacing around the values, I have borrowed code by [CarLaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570455/) to create an alternative to the environment `bmatrix` (named `bbmatrix`). This generally works, but fails inside my `\myrowvector` command, with a "Missing $ inserted" message. I don't quite follow the part of the code with `{+b}` and **I would appreciate a hint on how to use a matrix with greater spacing around values.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570455/
% CarLaTex
\NewDocumentEnvironment{bbmatrix}{+b}{
    \begin{+bmatrix}[columns={1.0em, c, colsep=2pt}]
    #1
    \end{+bmatrix}
    }{}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423115/
% user31729
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { myrowvector }
{
  values .clist_set:N = \l_myrowvector_values_clist,
}
\keys_define:nn { mycolvector }
{
  values .clist_set:N = \l_mycolvector_values_clist,
}
\NewDocumentCommand\myrowvector{m}{
  \keys_set:nn { myrowvector } { #1 }
    \ensuremath{
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_myrowvector_values_clist {
        ##1 &
      }
      \end{bmatrix}
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\mycolvector{m}{
  \keys_set:nn { mycolvector } { #1 }
    \ensuremath{
      \begin{bmatrix}
        \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_mycolvector_values_clist {
        ##1 \\
      }
      \end{bmatrix}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A row vector:
\begin{align*}
\myrowvector{values={1,2,3}}
\end{align*}

A column vector:
\begin{align*}
\mycolvector{values={1,2,3}}
\end{align*}

A less tightly spaced row vector:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bbmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bbmatrix}
\end{align*}

A less tightly spaced column vector:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bbmatrix}
1 \\ 2 \\ 3
\end{bbmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I have accepted egreg's answer, but for posterity I'd like to copy skillmon's comment, which solved the spacing problem:

Instead of `\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_mycolvector_values_clist { ##1 \\ }` try to use `\clist_use:Nn \l_mycolvector_values_clist { \\ }` (or `\clist_use:Nn \l_myrowvector_values_clist { & }` respectively). See for instance [tex.stackexchange.com/q/678399/117050](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678399/117050).

Also, I have since found this related question:  [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270223](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270223)

Comment: Instead of `\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_mycolvector_values_clist { ##1 \\ }` try to use `\clist_use:Nn \l_mycolvector_values_clist { \\ }` (or `\clist_use:Nn \l_myrowvector_values_clist { & }` respectively).

Comment: See for instance https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678399/117050

Comment: Thank you @Skillmon, this does the trick. I can't believe I didn't see your answer before. Now that the main problem is solved, it feels like a duplicate of that question. But the "api" is different and it's perhaps interesting to have an example of it on the site. I'd like to understand what you mean when you write "you can use `\clist_use:nn` instead of temporary assignments to some other variable." Also do you have any idea why the `bbmatrix` won't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `tabularray` environments don't like that `&` is hidden in macros, you want to use `+bmatrix` as a command rather than an environment.

And you want to exploit `\clist_use:Nn` rather than mapping.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{expl3}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% adapted from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570455/
% CarLaTex

\cs_new_protected:Nn \patrickt_bbmatrix:n
 {
  \begin{+bmatrix}[columns={1.0em, c, colsep=2pt}]
  #1
  \end{+bmatrix}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \patrickt_bbmatrix:n { e }

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423115/
% user31729
\keys_define:nn { patrickt/vector }
 {
  values .clist_set:N = \l_patrickt_vector_values_clist,
 }
\NewDocumentCommand\myrowvector{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { patrickt/vector } { #1 }
  \patrickt_bbmatrix:e { \clist_use:Nn \l_patrickt_vector_values_clist { & } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand\mycolvector{m}{
  \keys_set:nn { patrickt/vector } { #1 }
  \patrickt_bbmatrix:e { \clist_use:Nn \l_patrickt_vector_values_clist { \\ } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A row vector:
\begin{equation*}
\myrowvector{values={1,2,3}}
\end{equation*}

A column vector:
\begin{equation*}
\mycolvector{values={1,2,3}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

No need to define two different sets of keys. I also removed `\ensuremath` that has no real purpose and changed `align*` to `equation*` (never use the former for single equations).

[image]

On the other hand, I see no real reason to use a syntax like

```
\myrowvector{values={1,2,3}}
```

over

```
\myrowvector{1,2,3}
```

that you can accomplish with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% adapted from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570455/
% CarLaTex

\cs_new_protected:Nn \patrickt_bbmatrix:n
 {
  \begin{+bmatrix}[columns={1.0em, c, colsep=2pt}]
  #1
  \end{+bmatrix}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \patrickt_bbmatrix:n { e }

\NewDocumentCommand\myrowvector{m}
 {
  \patrickt_bbmatrix:e { \clist_use:nn { #1 } { & } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand\mycolvector{m}{
  \patrickt_bbmatrix:e { \clist_use:nn { #1 } { \\ } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A row vector:
\begin{equation*}
\myrowvector{1,2,3}
\end{equation*}

A column vector:
\begin{equation*}
\mycolvector{1,2,3}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

A different and “unified” approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% adapted from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570455/
% CarLaTex

\cs_new_protected:Nn \patrickt_bbmatrix:n
 {
  \begin{+bmatrix}[columns={1.0em, c, colsep=2pt}]
  #1
  \end{+bmatrix}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \patrickt_bbmatrix:n { V }

\NewDocumentCommand\mymatrix{m}
 {
  \__patrickt_bbmatrix_build:n { #1 }
  \patrickt_bbmatrix:V \l__patrickt_bbmatrix_body_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l__patrickt_bbmatrix_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__patrickt_bbmatrix_rows_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__patrickt_bbmatrix_build:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__patrickt_bbmatrix_rows_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \tl_clear:N \l__patrickt_bbmatrix_body_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__patrickt_bbmatrix_rows_seq
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__patrickt_bbmatrix_body_tl { \clist_use:nn { ##1 } { & } \exp_not:N \\ }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mymatrix{1,2,3}\ne
\mymatrix{1;2;3}\ne
\mymatrix{1,2;3,4;5,6}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's great, thanks egreg for another wonderful answer! I had used the syntax values= because it's what I'd come across first in the post I linked to in my question. Since then @skillmon has shown me closely related questions I had missed. But perhaps this more verbose syntax will come in handy if I define the data (the values) in an external file I read in (my original plan, not mentioned in my question)? I also had another plan to have a command to transpose. If I get there. For everyday usage the simpler syntax is definitely more convenient!

Comment: @PatrickT Just try it yourself by comparing the example I showed when `equation*` is replaced by `align*`.

Comment: @PatrickT Try when the line preceding the display is short.

Comment: just noticed that this only works well for single digits, e.g.`\mymatrix{1.01,2.01,3.01}` gets the digits cramped.

Comment: @PatrickT That's the setting you asked to `tblr`, isn't it? Namely `columns={1.0em,...}`

Comment: Oh, I see! I had copied that from the original code without paying attention. Thanks!